# Saving files to public Download directory

Tags: android, file, kotlin

Before Android Q below code worked fine (this has now been deprecated) to access downloads public storage directory:

```
var publicExternalFilesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

This referred to below path on emulator:

> /mnt/sdcard/Download/

Is there any way we can refer to above path safely on Android Q and above

Comment: Of course. Like before. Nothing changed. Deprecation is removed.

Comment: `/mnt/sdcard/Download/` Strange emulator. Normally we see /storage/emulated/0/Download.

Comment: So we can still use getexternalstoragepublicdirectory and expect to work in near future and currently on playstore?

Comment: Can you point me towards deprecation removed manual on Android documentation, thanks !

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String) here it still says that it's deprecated in API 29